# BigQuery google analytics users who triggered two events

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have the following which is returning me two values but I want to be able to see the merged results, i.e the users who meet the criteria (in the table) who triggered both events, not just triggered either event.

```
SELECT event_param.value.string_value, COUNT (DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS total_users
FROM `*****`,
UNNEST (event_params) AS event_param
WHERE (event_name = 'select_content' 
AND event_param.key = 'content_type'
AND event_param.value.string_value = 'Q12')
GROUP BY event_param.value.string_value
UNION ALL
SELECT event_param.value.string_value, COUNT (DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS answer_users
FROM `*****`,
UNNEST (event_params) AS event_param
WHERE (event_name = 'select_content' 
AND event_param.key = 'content_id'
AND event_param.value.string_value = 'Option_C')
GROUP BY event_param.value.string_value
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two similar sub-queries appended with UNION statement. I suggest updating the first sub-query and removing the second:

```
SELECT event_param.value.string_value, COUNT (DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS total_users
FROM `*****`,
UNNEST (event_params) AS event_param
WHERE event_name = 'select_content' 
AND ((event_param.key = 'content_type'
  AND event_param.value.string_value = 'Q12') 
  OR (event_param.key = 'content_id'
  AND event_param.value.string_value = 'Option_C'))
GROUP BY event_param.value.string_value
```